# C# StreamWriter in separate class

Tags: c#, winforms, class, methods, streamwriter

I have a Textbox and a button in form1, and when i write in the textbox i can save it to a file on the computer using my button. This is placed inside my button

```
    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string FileName = "C:\\sample\\sample.txt";
        System.IO.StreamWriter WriteToFile;
        WriteToFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(FileName);
        WriteToFile.Write(textBox1.Text);
        WriteToFile.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Succeded, written to file");
```

But anyway, I want to move everything to do with streamWriter to their own class (Class1) and call it from my main form, inside the button. 
If i move all the content insde the Button and move it to class1 inside a method, it claims that Textbox1 doesn't exist, obvious.

Do you have any tips or links on what i should read more about?

Best Regards
DB

Comment: pass `textBox1.Text` as parameter of method

Comment: as a best practice, I would also recomend opening the StreamWriter in a using statement, or have the class using it implement the IDisposable interface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in the class like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static bool WriteToFile(string text){
        string FileName = "C:\\sample\\sample.txt";
        try {
            using(System.IO.StreamWriter WriteToFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(FileName)){
                WriteToFile.Write(text);
                WriteToFile.Close();
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And in your button event:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if(MyClass.WriteToFile(textBox1.Text))
        MessageBox.Show("Succeded, written to file");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Failer, nothing written to file");
}
```

Comment: I would move the MessageBox call from the class to the location where the method is called. Also add some error handling to the WriteToFile method and optionally have it return a bool for success / fail.

Comment: For something as simple as this I'd make it a static function/class, so you can just call `MyClass.WriteToFile(textBox1.Text);` Also, as already remarked, make it return a boolean with the success status.

Comment: Racil Hilan, thanks for your explanation. I will mark your answer as accepted. The problem for me was that i did not know how to pass the textBox1 to my method. I forgott to add an in parameter as well. 

I will also check your suggestions Boxstart and Nyerguds.

Comment: I fully agree with the suggestions. Updated the answer. Of course, ideally you should do some validation on the `textBox1.text` before you attempt to write it to the file.